# Given two strings, check if they're k-equal, every substring of length k appear on both and has to be max

Tags: java, string, hashmap, substring

I'm trying to solve a problem: Given 2 strings, I need to check if they're k-equal, meaning every sub string of length k in str1 appears in str2 and vice versa. The number of occurnces of the sub-strings does not have to be equal though. we can assume that the string are zero equal by default. Lastly, the k has to be the highest number we can find. thus if there are sub-strings of length 1 and length 2 that appear on both strings, we should return just the strings with length 2.

How can I approach this with Collections? for example with HashMap.

Example:[image]

Comment: I'd just put every substring for a given k from str1 into a `Set` (a `HashSet` might work well enough), let's call it set1. Then I'd do the same for every substring from str2 and put it into another set2. While collecting the substrings for set2, I'd check if the string is already in set1 - if not, then we can abort right away. I *think* if the size of both sets is equal, then that is enough to say (after the previous check) that they are k-equal for the given k. Start with k = 1 and increment after every iteration, until you find a k where it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: @CrushaK.Rool Sounds like a good idea. I will update you asap. Thx!

Answer (score 0):

Hash all substring of str1 in a HashSet, lets say hash1.
Now generate substrings of str2 and check if it exists in hash1 and also maintain a max variable .
I thinks this should work but its kind of bruteforce approach.

Comment: A `HashSet` should be enough, rather than using a `HashMap`. With a `Set`, you keep track of whether or not something is *there*. A `Map` is used to associate a key with a value, so it would be overkill for this.